# Which missions do I have to finish so that I can do all actions in the open world of Red Dead Redemption 2?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

As it turns out, I tried to free roam in the Wild West too early. I wasn't even able to [unsaddle my horse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/340702/how-to-unsaddle-my-horse-in-red-dead-redemption-2?noredirect=1#comment481772_340702).

So before I venture out the next time, I want to unlock all side-actions and activities.

Which missions do I have to tackle that allow me to truly roam free?  By that I mean go hunting and fishing, finding treasures, and side-games like poker as all I see is domino.

I am looking for a list of quest-giver, quest name, and what it unlocks, e.g.:

- Hosea Matthews, "Exit Pursued by a Bruised Ego", unlocks the stable, unsaddling of horses, and grants you the brush for horse grooming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CHAPTER 1: Colter

- Dutch van der Linde (automatically after *Who the Hell is Leviticus Cornwall?*) - *Eastward Bound* - **Unlocks the open world**

CHAPTER 2: Horseshoe Overlook

- Hosea Matthews - *Exit Pursued by a Bruised Ego* - Unlocks Horse Brush and the Legendary Animals map
- Leopold Strauss - *Money Lending and Other Sins* - Unlocks Ledger and Camp Upgrades
- Hosea Matthews - *The Spines of America* - Unlocks Fence to sell Gold Bars
- Abigail Marston - *A Fisher of Men* - Unlocks Fishing and Fishing Pole
- Dutch Van Der Linde - *A Strange Kindness* - Gives you a Gold Bar

CHAPTER 3: Clemens Point

- John Marston - *Horse Flesh for Dinner* - Unlocks Horse Fence
- Hosea Matthews - *The Fine Joys of Tobacco* - Makes Fire Bottles purchasable at fences
- Dutch Van Der Linde (automatically after *Blood Feuds, Ancient and Modern*) - *The Battle of Shady Belle* - Unlocks Chapter 4, and better horses at Scarlett Meadows Stable and Saint Denis Stable

CHAPTER 4: Saint Denis

- Dutch van der Linde - *Urban Pleasures* - Improved Dead-Eye skill

EPILOGUE 1: Pronghorn Ranch

- Abigail Marston (automatically after *Fatherhood, For Idiots*) - *Motherhood* - You get access to Arthur's weapons and items after this mission.

OTHER

- Curtis Malloy, sheriff of Valentine - Unlock bounties

Comment: Basically, completing chapter 2 will equip you with all the skills, equipment, and experience that you need in order to go out into the world and chase down all of those collectables.

Answer (score 0):

You're free to roam at chapter 3. Up until then it's basically a tutorial. It may be possible towards end of chapter 2 but I'd do it at chapter 3 to get a good sense of the game.